# Capturing before maximize or restore events in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, events

On downsizing from maximize, I need to set the height and width of the form to a certain value. To do this I am capturing maximize and restore events of the form using the re size event of the form. Now, the problem is that the event gets triggered after the form has maximized or restored. So, the form first downsizes to certain height and width and then I set the height width I need to set for the form. This transition looks very untidy.

So, I somehow need to capture the before restore and before maximize events of the form. So, that I can declare the size before it changes its size. Please suggest if this is possible, if no what can be a better way to handle these kind of transition.

Below is the code I am using now to capture the restore and maximize events:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnResize(e)
    Select Case Me.WindowState
        Case FormWindowState.Normal
            MessageBox.Show("Form was restored",
            Application.ProductName)
        Case FormWindowState.Minimized
            MessageBox.Show("Form was minimized",
            Application.ProductName)
        Case FormWindowState.Maximized
            MessageBox.Show("Form was maximized",
            Application.ProductName)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [`Form.WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc.aspx) method:

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
    Const SC_RESTORE As Integer    = &HF120
    Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer   = &HF030

    If m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND Then
        If m.WParam = New IntPtr(SC_RESTORE) Then
            ' do something before restore
            Me.Size = New Size(666, 666)
        ElseIf m.WParam = New IntPtr(SC_MAXIMIZE) Then
            ' do something before maximize
        End If
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)  ' allow form to process this message
End Sub
```

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the list of other commands.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already tried this. This works similar to the resize event method. So, this informs me after the form has been downsized.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    If WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        Me.Size = New Size(iWidth, iHeight)
    End If
End Sub
```